# How to replicate typeform using react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typeform

I am new to react js and I want to create a form like typeform, but I am not using typeform. I have a list of 5 questions and I want it to come one by one after user click on 'Next' with a sliding effect just like typeform.

The question can come from json data also. I have just used one approach.

Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-firefly-2c47h

Comment: Looks like you have achieved the multi-page form, what is your question now?

Comment: See if steppers help for your usecase https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/ as they can give progress on the form completion

Comment: @karthikdivi I am getting forms but on click of next previous one should hide.

Answer (score 9):

I have spent 2 years developing a full open source Typeform clone project based on React and Typescript. You can view it on Github [here](https://github.com/quillforms/quillforms). 
The project name is: Quill Forms. 
You can view the codesandbox example here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/quill-forms-example-20uuf

Comment: the codesandbox doesn't seem to work. Nevertheless amazing work!

Comment: @VivasvanPatel, Thanks for reporting this. 
I have fixed it and it should work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

For a Typeform-like experience using [React](https://reactjs.org), [Angular](https://angular.io), and [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org), have look at [Conversational Form](https://space10-community.github.io/conversational-form/landingpage/).

It provides a rich experience with a variety of input fields including checkboxes, radio boxes, images and etc.